# I need to set a pdf file from controller using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I found this example that opens in a modal or pop ups a PDF file .

[Example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1261/)
This example of my Javascript code that sets the pdf file by taking it from the folder, but I need to need to set the file from a controller function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var fileName = "Example.pdf";
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: fileName,
                    width: 540,
                    height: 450,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {
                        var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" 
 width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                        object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href=\"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                        object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                        object += "</object>";
                        object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName);
                        $("#dialog").html(object);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But you would have to set the pdf file from a controller doing something like this to call the controller but I want to know how to inject this controller into the JavaScript code to be able to set the file that I want to display.

```
src="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { Model.Id })"
```